# Memory allocation of string literal in c

Tags: memory-management, string-literals

I am having a strange issue with memory allocation in c, the file is fairly complicated so I cannot include it all here but perhaps you can point me in the right direction as to why this may be happening.

I am trying to create a string literal as such:

```
char * p = "root"
```

But when i look at the value of this variable at runtime (at the line directly after the declaration) i get this:

```
$1 = 0x7001260c "me"
```

and when I look at the contents of the memory at `0x7001260c` it indeed holds the string "me".

EDIT:
To give more context when I run the following code the value of p on the last line is `"root"`.

```
  create_directory("root/home");
  char * p = "root";
  char * q = "foo";
```

And when I run the following code the value of p is `"io"`

```
  create_directory("io/home");
  char * p = "root";
  char * q = "foo";
```

The `create_directory` function:

```
void create_directory(char * path) {
  directory d;
  directory * dir = &d;
  //Browse to closest directory
  path = find_directory(path, dir);
  //Create remaining directories
  char component[20];
  path = next_component(path, component);
  while (strlen(component) > 0) {
    add_dir_entry(dir, component, inode_next);
    write_dir_entry(dir, inode_to_loc(dir->inode));
    directory new;
    new.type = DIRECTORY;
    new.inode = inode_next;
    write_dir_entry(&new, inode_to_loc(inode_next));
    inode_next++;
    dir = &new;

    path = next_component(path, component);
  }
}
```

Comment: If `find_directory` modifies what its first parameter points to, that's your problem. You call `create_directory` with `path` pointing to a string constant. Then you pass that pointer to a string constant to `find_directory`. If `find_directory` modifies what `path` points to, it would be modifying a constant.

Comment: Either `create_directory` is supposed to modify what `path` points to or it isn't. If it is supposed to modify what `path` points to, calling it with a string constant is clearly wrong. If it's not supposed to modify what `path` points to, change it to take `path` as a `char const*`. Then see what breaks and fix it, eventually you'll find the bug, likely in `find_directory` or `next_component`.

Comment: I just noticed another bug in your code. The first time in the `while` loop, you set `dir` to point to the first instance of `new`. But then the second time in the `while` loop, you pass `dir` to `add_dir_entry` -- but `dir` now points to where the first instance of `new` was back when it existed. Ouch. In the second iteration of the `while` loop, the `new` from the first instance no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly, there's a bug somewhere in your program that causes a constant to be modified which is, of course, illegal. Perhaps you're doing something like this:

```
void to_lower(char *j)
{
    while (*j != 0) { *j = tolower(*j); j++; }
}

...

bool is_yes(char *k)
{
    to_lower(k);
    return strcmp(k, "yes") == 0;
}

void someFunc(char *k)
{
   if (is_yes(k)) // ...
   ...
}

someFunc("testing");
```

See what this does? We pass a pointer to a constant to `sumeFunc`, but it flows down to `to_lower` which modifies the thing it points to -- modifying a constant.

Somehow, your code probably does something like that.

Start by changing code like `char * p = "root"` to code like `char const* p = "root"`. That will give you a better chance of catching this kind of problem at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could be happening, I check the value of p on the line immediately below its declaration, it is not passed into any function or anything that could change its value.

Comment: @BenJacob It doesn't have to be `p` or anywhere near that code. It can be in different code entirely, but most likely, code manipulating the same string constant. So look for other instances of `"root"`.

Comment: I'm not confident that I know how C handles string constants, I have added some context to the question, would you mind explaining what might be going on? Many thanks.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, `find_directory` does not change what path points to but `next_component` does. I vaguely knew that string literals were treated differently but I couldn't remember what effect that would have. Thank you!

Comment: See my comment to the question for another bug in your code. You dereference a pointer to an object that no longer exists. Use `const` -- it will find these kinds of bugs before they happen.